# subset matrix using find function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I made a matrix in Matlab, say,

```
A = magic(5);
A =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

Now I found the indices I want using the find function as:

```
ind = find(A(:,5)>3 & A(:,4)>= 8);
ind =

     1
     2
     3
```

Now if I want to get a subset of matrix A for those indices using B = A(ind) function, I only get the first column of the matrix:

```
B = A(ind)
B =

    17
    23
     4
```

How can I get all the columns as subset??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops ... I got it

```
B = A(ind,:);
```